# JSON data convert to Java Object

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa

This post is in continuation of [JPA : Not able to persist record due to incorrect values being passed from client to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164282/jpa-not-able-to-persist-record-due-to-incorrect-values-being-passed-from-clien)

When I retrieve values from server JSON output is in the following format.

```
   {"emp":[{"dept":{"deptNo":"10","dname":"ACCOUNTING","loc": 
  "NEW YORK"},"empno":"7934","ename":"MILLER","hiredate":
  "1982-01-23T00:00:00+03:00","job":"CLERK","mgr":"7782","sal":"1300"},
  {"dept":
  {"deptNo":"20","dname":"RESEARCH","loc":"DALLAS"},"empno":"7902","ename":
  "FORD",
  "hiredate":"1981-12-03T00:00:00+03:00","job":"ANALYST","mgr":"7566","sal":
  "3000"},{"dept": 
  {"deptNo":"30","dname":"SALES","loc":"CHICAGO"},"empno":"7900","ename":
  "JAMES", "hiredate":
  "1981-12-03T00:00:00+03:00","job":"CLERK","mgr":"7698","sal":"950"},
  {"dept":{"deptNo":"20","dname":"RESEARCH","loc":"DALLAS"},"empno":"7876",
  "ename":
  "ADAMS","hiredate":
  "1987-05-23T00:00:00+03:00","job":"CLERK","mgr":"7788","sal":"1100"},
  {"comm":"0","dept":      
  {"deptNo":"30","dname":"SALES","loc":"CHICAGO"},"empno":"7844","ename":
  "TURNER","hiredate":
  "1981-09-08T00:00:00+03:00","job":"SALESMAN","mgr":"7698","sal":"1500"},
  {"dept":{"deptNo":"10","dname":"ACCOUNTING","loc":
  "NEW YORK"},"empno":"7839","ename":"KING","hiredate":
  "1981-11-17T00:00:00+03:00","job":"PRESIDENT","sal":"5000"},         
  {"dept":"deptNo":"20","dname":"RESEARCH","loc":"DALLAS"},"empno":"7788",
  "ename":"SCOTT","hiredate":
  "1987-04-19T00:00:00+03:00","job":"ANALYST","mgr":"7566","sal":"3000"},
   {"dept":{"deptNo":"10","dname":"ACCOUNTING","loc":
   "NEW YORK"},"empno":"7782","ename":"CLARK","hiredate":
   "1981-06-09T00:00:00+03:00","job":"MANAGER","mgr":"7839","sal":"2450"},
   {"dept":"deptNo":"30","dname":"SALES","loc":"CHICAGO"},"empno":"7698",
   "ename":
    "BLAKE","hiredate":
   "1981-05-01T00:00:00+03:00","job":"MANAGER","mgr":"7839","sal":"2850"},
   {"comm":"1400","dept": 
   {"deptNo":"30","dname":"SALES","loc":"CHICAGO"},"empno":"7654","ename":
    "MARTIN","hiredate":
   "1981-09-28T00:00:00+03:00","job":"SALESMAN","mgr":"7698","sal":"1250"},
   {"dept":
   {"deptNo":"20","dname":"RESEARCH","loc":"DALLAS"},"empno":"7566","ename": 
    "JONES","hiredate":
   "1981-04-02T00:00:00+03:00","job":"MANAGER","mgr":"7839","sal":"2975"},
   {"comm":"500","dept": 
   {"deptNo":"30","dname":"SALES","loc":"CHICAGO"},"empno":"7521","ename":
   "WARD", "hiredate":
   "1981-02-22T00:00:00+03:00","job":"SALESMAN","mgr":"7698","sal":"1250"},
    {"comm":"300","dept":
    {"deptNo":"30","dname":"SALES","loc":"CHICAGO"},"empno":"7499",
   "ename":
   "ALLEN","hiredate":"1981-02-20T00:00:00+03:00","job":"SALESMAN","mgr":
   "7698",
   "sal":"1600"},{"dept":
   {"deptNo":"20","dname":"RESEARCH","loc":"DALLAS"},"empno":"7369","ename":
    "SMITH","hiredate":
   "1980-12-17T00:00:00+03:00","job":"CLERK","mgr":"7902","sal":"800"}]}
```

If I would want to insert data into EMP table, how the data is expected and how can I pass that data from client JSON to server?

I have the tried the following format, however it didn't help.

```
function formToJSON() {
      return JSON.stringify({
                    "deptNo": "10",
                    "empno": "9004",
                    "ename": "JILL",
                    "job": "mfg",
                    "mgr": 34,
                    "sal": 456,
                    "comm": 900
                });
            }


$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Test1/rest/employee/",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formToJSON(),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        // console : 'ok',
                    })
                });
            });
```

When I submit from browser, deptNo is zero when I receive in server.
How it is expected in server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are sending wrong json format to server that's why you are getting deptNo = 0.

Correct Json format is like this.

```
{
    "deptNo":{
          "deptNo":500,
          "dname":"RESEARCH",
          "loc":"DALLAS"
       },
       "empno":7876,
       "ename":"ADAMS",
       "job":"1100",
       "sal":"7788"
    }
```

You can stringify your json as below

```
function formToJSON() {

  var test = {  empno:7876, ename:'ADAMS', job:1100, sal:7788,
                 deptNo:{deptNo:6, dname:'RESEARCH', loc:'DALLAS'}
               };

    return JSON.stringify(test);

    }
```

The continuation post of JPA : [Not able to persist record due to incorrect values being passed from client to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164282/jpa-not-able-to-persist-record-due-to-incorrect-values-being-passed-from-clien)

Also has this json format problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has really helped to resolve the issue, appreciated.